# Jax-rs 500 errors not displaying correct message or stack trace in grails

Tags: grails, jax-rs, cxf

I have a jax-rs Rest service that is called by Grails (2.4.3). using cxf

I have an exceptionMapper in the WS that wraps all exceptions and returns the original message/stack trace.

If I make a postMan request to the webservice I can see my exceptions just fine. However if I call the same method from grails, the exception is not there and I see a generic InternalServerError 500.  I put a breakpoint on the exceptionMapper on the WS and it is definitely getting hit.  But grails doesn't see it.  If I surround the call with a try/catch and inspect the exception in a debugger I see no trace of the exception.

What is grails doing differently than postMan? Is there a configuration I'm missing somewhere?